# Drag&Drop text to from a browser in to a textbox in Adobe Indesign

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, adobe-indesign

I want to Drag&Drop Text-Content from my Webbrowser (Firefox) into a textbox in Adobe Indesign.

If you drag a link like  into the textbox in Indesign, the content inside the textbox is: http://www.link.de

But I want drag some generated text (with php) and drop it in the textbox in Indesign.

Does anybody has an idea?

Comment: I bet Indesign textboxes already support dropping text from anywhere - do you have trouble selecting and dragging the text?

Comment: I do retrieve the text contents myself and not the url itself.

Comment: I drag the <a> tag link and drop it inside the textbox. The text is only the URL. I am not talking about Copy&Paste.